# Help with tricky integral of rational function that deals with positive and negative cases?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{dx}{1+k+(1-k)x^2}$$ for all values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now when $-1 \le k \le 1$ this integral is trivial by using inverse tangent substitution.

But this doesn't work when $|k|>1$. So why can't you evaluate the integral using this method, and how do you evaluate it then? (especially when $k$ is negative)

Is it possible to work out the definite integral with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: Notice $\tan^{-1}(ix) = i\tanh^{-1}(x) = \frac{i}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$. When $|k| > 1$, you use inverse hyperbolic tangent instead of inverse tangent as substitution. At the end, you get something involves logarithms. You can get the same result if you perform partial decomposition of fractions to the integrand.

Comment: Write the denominator as $1+k-(k-1)x^2$ for $|k|>1$

Answer (score 1):

For $k > 1$, we can rewrite the integral as
$$\frac{1}{k + 1} \int \frac{dx}{1 - \frac{k - 1}{k + 1} x^2} = \frac{1}{k + 1} \int \frac{dx}{1 - \left(\sqrt{\frac{k - 1}{k + 1}} x\right)^2},$$
which suggests the substitution $\sin \theta = \sqrt{\frac{k - 1}{k + 1}} x$ (or a suitable hyperbolic substitution, or partial fractions, though the last of these works out to be slightly messy).

The case $k < -1$ can be handled similarly.

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative is equal to $$\frac{1}{1-k}\sqrt{\frac{1-k}{1+k}}atan(\sqrt{\frac{1-k}{1+k}}x)$$ for k not equal to 1 or -1 and if $\frac{1-k}{1+k}$ >=0. The case k=1 is trivial. For k=-1 the antiderivative is $$\frac{-1}{2x}$$
If $\frac{1-k}{1+k}$ <0 the you can use simple fraction to integrate.